# AnsiNext- Function, C

Tags: c, function

Can someone explain me what the function `AnsiNext()` actually does?
I think it has something to do with reading a file.

Code example:

```
if (*pText == '\n')
    iNumLines++;
pText = AnsiNext(pText);
```

In the Internet I didn't find an explanation. Only a few tips but that is not enough. Please give me a fast explanation if You know it.
Thanks, peace.

(I want to read out a few lines of a txt.)

Comment: From [here](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32AnsiNext.htm) *"**AnsiNext** The `AnsiNext` function is obsolete. For compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows, this function is implemented as a macro that calls the `CharNext` function, which should be used for new Win32-based applications."* It don't know if this is up-to-date (since it talks about migration from 16-bit to 32-bit) but was the first result listed when searching for `AnsiNext`.

Answer (score 0):

The `AnsiNext()` function ([which is obsolete](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32AnsiNext.htm)) is used to get a pointer to the next character in a string after that pointed to by the given argument.

So, in the following code, the `p0` pointer will reference the *first* character in the `test` array (`'a'`) and, after the call to `AnsiNext`, the `p1` pointer will reference the following character in that string (`'b'`).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h> // This implicitly includes <winuser.h>

int main()
{
    char test[] = "abcdefg";
    char* p0 = test;
    char* p1 = AnsiNext(p0);
    printf("%c %c\n", *p0, *p1);
    return 0;
}
```

For backwards compatibility with code that uses this obsolete function, it is defined as a macro (in the `<winuser.h>` header file) to defer to the `CharNextA` function (even when compiling using the `_UNICODE` character set).

```c
/* winuser.h --*/
//...
#define AnsiNext CharNextA
```